# What is wrong with my jQuery Deferred() usage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to use Deferred to correctly order delete calls to an API. The application deals with Items and Images:

```
Item:
ItemId

Images:
ImageId
ItemId
```

so Images must be deleted before the Item it is associated with can be deleted, otherwise my DeleteItem() ajax call will return an error in the data object.

In the code below I am trying to group all of the DeleteImage() ajax calls before any DeleteItem() ajax calls are made.

```
var deferreds1 = [];  
var deferreds2 = [];   

...
// push()ing an unknown number of DeleteImage() ajax calls to deferred1 
// push()ing an unknown number of DeleteItem() ajax calls to deferred2
...

if (deferreds1.length > 0) {
    $.when
        .apply($, deferreds1)
        .then(function(){
             console.log('deferred1 then');
             $.when
                  .apply($, deferreds2)
                  .then(function() {
                       console.log('deferred2 then');
                  })
                  .fail(function() {
                       console.log('deferred2 fail');
                  });
             })
         .fail(function(){
              console.log('deferred1 fail');
         });
}

function DeleteItemImage() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                alert('error');
            }
            dfd.resolve();
        }
        ...
    }); 

    return dfd.promise();
}

function DeleteItem() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                alert('error');
            }
            dfd.resolve();
        }
        ...
    }); 

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

It seems the calls are being made in the intended order most of the time, but not all the time. Help me find the one little detail I'm sure I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling your `DeleteItem` function before all the `DeleteItemImage` deferreds are resolved.  I think you need to do this instead.

```
var deferreds1 = [];  
var deferreds2 = [];   

...
// push()ing an unknown number of DeleteImage() ajax calls to deferred1 
// do not call DeleteItem here.  Wait until all of deferreds1 are resolved.
...

if (deferreds1.length > 0) {
    $.when
        .apply($, deferreds1)
        .done(function(){
             console.log('deferred1 done');
             // NOW call DeleteItem and add to deferreds2,
             // since now all the Images are deleted.
             deferreds2.push(DeleteItem()); // for each item...
             $.when
                  .apply($, deferreds2)
                  .done(function() {
                       console.log('deferred2 done');
                  })
                  .fail(function() {
                       console.log('deferred2 fail');
                  });
             })
         .fail(function(){
              console.log('deferred1 fail');
         });
}
```